# Proper layout resource folder for Amazon Kindle HDX 7" HD screen

Tags: android, android-layout, dpi, multiscreen

I have a new device to port my app to (Kindle Fire HDX)

The `DisplayMetrics` dump:

```
DPI : 320, 
wxh 1920x1200, 
x,y dpi 324.255x322.966, 
scaleddensity 2.0 
densityfactor 2.0
```

**What's the most accurate folder "swXXXdp" to place the layout resources? Can I calculate that "XXX" from the displayMetrics?**

- To target my 10.1 galaxy tab I use "`sw720dp`".
- To target an old 7" 1024x600 I use "`sw600dp`"
- This kindle fire seems it fetches the resources from "`sw600dp`" as well, but I don't fully understand why (as it is a much bigger resolution screen than the other 7")

Can anybody shed some light? Thx!

Comment: These resource configurations are based on screen size not resolution - "dp" stands for "density-independent pixel".

Comment: I'd go with "sw1200dp". See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) - " use the sw<N>dp configuration qualifier to define **the smallest available width**" (which is 1200, in your case)

Comment: @ArtooDetoo, So the number in sw<N> mean real screen pixels? or have I to multiply it by a density factor or something? Documentation is a bit confusing for me!

Comment: No, real pixels, in this case. dp is the preferred unit for smoothly scaling the contents inside layouts and sp is the preferred unit for the font sizes. Only when **in code** you are operating on pixels, then you use to multiply them by the density scale factor.

Comment: Hey @ArtoDetoo, check this out: https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/solutions/devices/kindle-fire/app-development/01--screen-layout-and-resolution ... looks like the scalefactor returned by displaymetrics affect the smallest width qualifier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally understood the **swXXXX** thing thanks to everybody's answers and a little research.

sw**XXXX** and sh**XXXX** do indeed mean Smallest Width and Smallest Height available, however the **Desity Factor** in the Display Metrics affect this value as well.

For instance

- the Amazon Kindle Fire HDX 7" has a "raw" resolution of 1920x1200, but the display is Ultra-dense (xhdpi), that's why the density factor is set to 2. So for resources, Android will look in sw(1200/2) == **sw600dp**.
- My older tablet, also 7", has a raw resolution of 1024x600, but the display is less dense, so DisplayMetrics return a density factor of 1, and the associated resource folder will be sw(600/1)dp == **sw600dp**
- The new "retina-like" 10" screens have a resolution around 2560x1600, but then again, the density factor is 2, so they're equivalent, when it comes to swXXXX layouts, to 1280x720 screens with density factor=1 (ie. Galaxy Tab): The folder is **sw720dp** in both cases.
- So although the layout folders are the same, Bitmap resources will be fetched according to the density code, which is different. The modern tablets I describe use xhdpi, while the older ones use mdpi or hdpi -can't remember right now-. This is why the final thing works: Same layouts use density-independent dimensions, and load density-dependent bitmaps. The final omelette tastes delicious!